# how to add assigned tasks to community

Tags: tasks, community, napili

I am creating a customer community using Napili Template and I want to add tasks to home page just like we see "My Taks" on the home page n salesforce. I am allowing external users to self login. 
I am able to add Case list to the community home page.

Please advise me how to add assigned tasks to community?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the customer community license supports Tasks. It does support the Case object.
If the user can't see the object, then adding that object to the community won't help.

Comment: I believe you're probably right based on the visibility of the Event sobject and its close relationship to Task.  Usually this help article is super helpful, but seems to be lacking Activities other than Event (Partner Community only).  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Oh okay. There is a option "My Account" at the upper right corner. When I click on that I can see my Person Account record details but but related open activities are not shown. Do I have to give access permission anywhere to access that? Or can I create any custom components to access the tasks list and then add it to my template page.

Comment: The Task object is not accessible to that user. You can't see it because the platform prevents all users with that license type from accessing the Task object.